# Perl XML::Twig send final output to JSON

Tags: json, xml, perl

I have the following code that erases the soap envelope and body of and XML string keeping the root and I want to take the final output and send to JSON. -thanks

```
use XML::Twig;
use JSON;

$xml = '<soap:Envelope><Servers>10.20.200.11</Servers></soap:Envelope>';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { Servers => 1 },
    twig_handlers => { 
        'soap:Envelope' => sub { $_->erase() },
    },
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
 );

 $twig->parse($xml); 

 my $output = $twig->print;

 $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;

 $pretty_printed = $json->pretty->encode($output); # <-- This dosen't work!!

 # finally print json
 print $pretty_printed;



So if the XML looks like this - I added a node
$xml = '<Envelope><Servers><Server>10.20.200.11</Server></Servers></Envelope>';

I would expect the JSON to look like this 

 {
   "Servers" : {
        "Server" : "10.20.200.11"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please always `use strict` and `use warnings` in your Perl code. Especially when asking for help here.

Comment: `$twig->print` prints a stringified XML version of the twig or tree, and returns the `$twig` object itself. So you are assigning `$twig` to `$output`. You then pass that object to JSON, which cannot convert it because it doesn't know what to do with a blessed data structure (i.e. an object). XML is way more complex than JSON can be, having an additional dimension. For your example there are already several ways to encode that in JSON. How do you want it to map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 my $output = $twig->print;
```

I think you want

```
 my $output = $twig->sprint;
```

there, so you get the string back instead of the twig object (thanks simbabque)

this will just output the variable as a JSON string though, not generate a data structure from the XML

Comment: This worked like a charm $json->pretty->encode($twig->sprint); Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

[XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) has [a `simplify` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#simplify-(%25options)) that works similar to [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) (which should not be used!). You could use that, but it's not very helpful for your example.

```
my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
my $pretty_printed = $json->pretty->encode( $twig->simplify );
```

This will output

```
"10.20.200.11"
```

That's valid JSON, but it's missing the `Servers`. I would expect something like

```
{ "Servers" => "10.20.200.11" }
```

In [XML::Simple the `KeepRoot` option](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#KeepRoot-=%3E-1-%23-in+out-handy) would do that, and XML::Twig's doc claims one should look at XML::Simple's docs for the options to `simplify`.

> Return a data structure suspiciously similar to XML::Simple's. Options are identical to XMLin options, see XML::Simple doc for more details (or use DATA::dumper or YAML to dump the data structure)

However, it [does not allow](https://github.com/mirod/xmltwig/blob/master/Twig.pm#L7273) that option.

---

A better plan might be to write your own code to allow for a conversion based specifically on the format you want.